# How to count exact words in sentences?

Tags: excel, count

There is a table for example,

```
Example data: 

      ColumnA |       ColumnB                                 | 

ROW1  Code1   | There is an apple, and there wasn't an apple. |

ROW2  Code2   | The applepie is tasty.                        |

ROW3  Code3   | Apple is good for people.                     |

ROW4  Code4   | We buy the apple, and they sell apples!       |

     --------

The result I hope to show: 

      ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE | ColumnF |
ROW5  apple   |  4      | Code1   | Code3   | Code4   |         |
ROW6  apples  |  1      | Code4   |         |         |         |
ROW7  the     |  2      | Code2   | Code4   |         |         |
```

I hope to write some formula to ...

(1) **How to write formula for B5, B6?**

There are two exact words at A5,A6.
B5~B7 will show numbers that the sentence from B1:B4 matches the exact word(A5~A7).

(2) **How to write formula for C5~F5,C6~F6?**

Because the exact word "apple" is conclued in B1, B3, B4. I want to show the value at A1, A3, A4.

Because the exact word "the" is conclued in B2, B4. I want to show the value at A2, A4.

**I've tried some formula, but can't perfect work.**

**Could you please help me with this question? Thanks for you help.**

Comment: In your example, none of the sentences contain any punctuation. Does that mean that there is never any? If not, in order to be sure of guaranteeing correct results, you would need to provide a definitive list of all punctuation marks which could occur in a given sentence (writing a formula which checks for all possible punctuation marks would be overkill).

Comment: Is VBA an option?  If so, a Regex solution would be possible

Comment: @JosWoolley Hi, I edit the question again. I add some sentences. Thanks.

Comment: @James Thanks, but I don't think you understood my point. Are you saying with your new examples that the ONLY punctuation marks possible are the comma, period and exclamation mark?

Comment: @JosWoolley Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry, I think examples will not only just comma, period and exclamation mark. ><

Comment: @James So, as I said, you need to provide a list of ALL possible punctuation marks which could occur. The alternative would be to write a very long formula which first removes all known punctuation marks in the English language.

Comment: @JosWoolley Hi, I see... Is it possible to add a punctuation  list such as below?
'''
            Column G
Row1          ,
Row2          .
Row3          ?
......             ......
'''

And the formula will consider G:G , so that I can add the new punctuation when I see the new sentence ?

Comment: In agreement with @chrisneilsen, this would be fairly simple using VBA and/or Power Query.  Remove punctuation; split the sentence into an array of words; count the words and retain the original "Code". You may need to decide if you want a case-sensitive or case-insensitve count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Excel 2013`, assuming the same layout as per `JvdV`'s screenshot, and that you place your punctuation marks in `C1`, `C2` and `C3`, formula in `E1`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(2+LEN(B$1:B$4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(" "&B$1:B$4&" "),C$1," "),C$2," "),C$3," ")," "&D1&" ","")))/(2+LEN(D1))`

and copied down.

An additional `SUBSTITUTE` clause will be required for each additional punctuation mark added below that in `C3`. For example, with a new entry in `C4`, the above becomes:

`=SUMPRODUCT(2+LEN(B$1:B$4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(" "&B$1:B$4&" "),C$1," "),C$2," "),C$3," "),C$4," ")," "&D1&" ","")))/(2+LEN(D1))`

Then, for the lists, in `F1`:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$4)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$4))+1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$D1&" ",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(" "&$B$1:$B$4&" "),$C$1," "),$C$2," "),$C$3," "))),COLUMNS($F1:F1))),"")`

and copied right until you start to get blanks for the results. This formula can also be copied down to `F2`, `F3`, etc.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the solution. It works in Excel 2013.
Btw, Could you help me with the formula for the C5:F7(correspond to the example I wrote) ?

Comment: @James Done. Note that I moved the punctuation from column G to column C and revised the formulas accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It can works.